# C# delete from dbf where x=1 AND y=2

Tags: c#, sql, oledb, sql-delete, dbf

I need to delete rows from dbf file using OLEDB.
Why this query doesn't work? Got error from database driver.

```
m_query1 = "DELETE FROM tablename WHERE N_U='VS1' AND QMONTH=1";
```

But this works fine:

```
m_query1 = "DELETE FROM tablename WHERE N_U='VS1'";
m_query1 = "DELETE FROM tablename WHERE QMONTH=1";
```

ps. Error: Unexpected error from external database driver (10019)

ps2. It's works fine with ONE condition and double quotes.

Comment: Are the double quotes really intended? Afaik, their use is database dependent. `DELETE FROM tablename WHERE N_U='VS1' AND QMONTH=1`

Comment: Because there is no `N_U='VS1'`. By the way use single quotes in SQL. Many dialects understand both but SQL is single quotes usually. You can make an http://sqlfiddle.com/ to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: table contain N_U='VS1', single quotes checked, not help

Comment: share your connection string for OLEDB database

Comment: `string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Extended Properties=dBASE IV; Data Source={0}", FileHelper.GetDirectoryData());`

Comment: I found the problem. It's in the index file. I have index `M_QM` with expression `STR(QMONTH)+N_U+STR(MIXID)`.  All works fine when I remove this index. After re adding got error.

Answer (score 1):

SQL syntax on OLEDB & dbf files can be really specific.

Have you tried () around the AND clause?

I've had strange problems with OLEDB which didn't occur with ODBC drivers.

What connecting string are you using?

Hope this helps
B

Comment: `string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Extended Properties=dBASE IV; Data Source={0}", FileHelper.GetDirectoryData());`

Comment: I found the problem. It's in the index file. I have index `M_QM` with expression `STR(QMONTH)+N_U+STR(MIXID)`. All works fine when I remove this index. After re adding got error.